# Two's Complement Representation of int16_t

Tags: c, bit, twos-complement, uint16

I am attempting to display a string representation of an int16_t's Two's Complement. I find the two's complement by `(uint16_t)~value + 1;`

How would I add the 16 bits to a string?

```
char* getBits(const int16_t value) {

    uint16_t complement = (uint16_t)~value + 1;
    char bits = malloc(16*sizeof(char*))

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        bits[i] = // something
    }
    return bits;
}
```

Comment: Add `'\0'` to the end of `bits` and use `printf("%s", bits)`.

Comment: bits is empty??

Comment: Please do _not_ edit your original code based on a response here. It makes the answers posted nonsensical (e.g. Barmar's change from `char` to `char *`). You may edit your question and append additional code to the bottom. Or, you may show your final/updated in an answer of your own [if you wish].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift `complement` right `i` bits, and test whether the low-order bit is `0` or `1` and put the corresponding character in `bits`.

```
bits[i] = (complement >> i) & 1 ? '1' : '0';
```

Also, you need to allocate an extra character in your string for the null terminator. And `bits` needs to be a pointer, while the element size is `sizeof(char)`, not `sizeof(char*)`.

```
char *bits = malloc(17*sizeof(char));
bits[16] = 0;
```

There's no need to use the formula `(uint16_t)~value + 1`. Converting a signed int to unsigned int automatically returns its twos complement value. So you can simply do:

```
uint16_t complement = (uint16_t)value;
```

Comment: Why not malloc((16+1)*sizeof(char))

Comment: why sizeof(char)?

Comment: I tend not to remove that when the OP uses it. It's redundant but meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many issues and it wont even compile. You need to learn what is pointer and what is not. How to use malloc and where to sstore its result. The best way is to read a good C book.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* getBits(const int16_t value) 
{
    uint16_t complement = value;
    char *bits = malloc(sizeof(value) * CHAR_BIT + 1);
    char *wrk = bits;

    if(bits)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 1 << 15; i; i >>= 1) 
        {
            *wrk++ = (complement & i) ? '1' : '0';
        }
        *wrk++ = 0;
    }
    return bits;
}



int main(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i > -15; i --)
    {
        char *bits;
        printf("%d - %s\n", i, (bits = getBits(i)));
        free(bits);
    }
}
```